# DECODE( ) function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle

```
SELECT PC_COMP_CODE,
       'R',
       PC_RESUB_REF,
       DECODE(PC_SL_LDGR_CODE, '02', 'DR', 'CR'),
       PC_DEPT_NO DEPT,
       '', --PC_DEPT_NO,
       PC_SL_LDGR_CODE + '/' + PC_SL_ACNO,
       SUM(DECODE(PC_SL_LDGR_CODE, '02', 1, -1) * PC_AMOUNT),
       PC_CHEQUE_NO CHQNO
  FROM GLAS_PDC_CHEQUES
 WHERE PC_RESUB_REF IS NOT NULL 
   AND PC_DISCD NOT IN ('d', 'D', 'T') 
GROUP BY PC_RESUB_REF, 
         PC_COMP_CODE, 
         'JJ', 
         PC_SL_LDGR_CODE + '/' + PC_SL_ACNO, 
         PC_DEPT_NO, 
         PC_CHEQUE_NO, 
         DECODE(PC_SL_LDGR_CODE, '02', 'DR', 'CR')
```

Above is a Oracle query; how can I use DECODE() function in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: You may want to reformat the SQL a bit and elaborate on what the specific problem is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle Decode function equivalent in Sql Server 2005+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654084/oracle-decode-function-equivalent-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could use the 'CASE .. WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END' syntax in SQL.

Answer (score 36):

Just for completeness (because nobody else posted the most obvious answer):

Oracle:

```
DECODE(PC_SL_LDGR_CODE, '02', 'DR', 'CR')
```

MSSQL (2012+):

```
IIF(PC_SL_LDGR_CODE='02', 'DR', 'CR')
```

The bad news:

`DECODE` with more than 4 arguments would result in an ugly `IIF` cascade

Comment: IIF is SQL Server 2012 onwards - just as a caveat. The original question was on 2005 although most will of moved forward by now.

Comment: might be ugly be it doesn't impact performance.
ORDER BY
    IIF( %s = '1001-10000', 0,
    IIF( %s = '0-1000', 1,
    IIF( %s = '20001-30000', 2,
    IIF( %s = '10001-20000', 3,
    IIF( %s = 'Other', 4,
    5
    ))))) ASC

Answer (score 30):

If I understand the question correctly, you want the equivalent of decode but in T-SQL

```
Select YourFieldAliasName =
CASE PC_SL_LDGR_CODE
    WHEN '02' THEN 'DR'
    ELSE 'CR'
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a function in SQL Server as below and replace the `DECODE` with `dbo.DECODE`

```
CREATE FUNCTION DECODE(@CondField as nvarchar(100),@Criteria as nvarchar(100), 
                       @True Value as nvarchar(100), @FalseValue as nvarchar(100))
returns nvarchar(100)
begin
       return case when @CondField = @Criteria then @TrueValue 
                   else @FalseValue end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to do:

```
select 
    CASE WHEN 10 > 1 THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
END
```

Answer (score 3):

In my Case I used it in a lot of places first example if you have 2 values for select statement like gender (Male or Female) then use the following statement:

```
SELECT CASE Gender WHEN 'Male' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS Gender
```

If there is more than one condition like nationalities you can use it as the following statement:

```
SELECT CASE Nationality 
WHEN 'AMERICAN'   THEN 1 
WHEN 'BRITISH'   THEN 2
WHEN 'GERMAN'    THEN 3 
WHEN 'EGYPT'     THEN 4 
WHEN 'PALESTINE' THEN 5 
ELSE 6 END AS Nationality
```

Answer (score 2):

> when I use the function

```
select dbo.decode(10>1 ,'yes' ,'no')
```

> then say syntax error near '>'

Unfortunately, that does not get you around having the CASE clause in the SQL, since you would need it to convert the logical expression to a bit parameter to match the type of the first function argument:

```
create function decode(@var1 as bit, @var2 as nvarchar(100), @var3 as nvarchar(100))
returns nvarchar(100)
begin
return case when @var1 = 1 then @var2 else @var3 end;
end;

select dbo.decode(case when 10 > 1 then 1 else 0 end, 'Yes', 'No');
```

Answer (score 1):

join this "literal table",

```
select 
    t.c.value('@c', 'varchar(30)') code,
    t.c.value('@v', 'varchar(30)') val
from (select convert(xml, '<x c="CODE001" v="Value One" /><x c="CODE002" v="Value Two" />') aXmlCol) z
cross apply aXmlCol.nodes('/x') t(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value on which the selection depends is an integer, you can use the CHOOSE function:

[CHOOSE funtion in TSQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
CHOOSE ( index, val_1, val_2 [, val_n ] )
```

Citing the documentation:

*index*

Is an integer expression that represents a 1-based index into the list of the items following it.

If the provided index value has a numeric data type other than int, then the value is implicitly converted to an integer. If the index value exceeds the bounds of the array of values, then CHOOSE returns null.

*val_1 ... val_n*

List of comma separated values of any data type.

Answer (score 1):

While a `CASE` based solution works for most cases, it probably doesn't take into account `NULL` values. Oracle's `DECODE` is `NULL` safe, meaning that

```sql
DECODE(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

Translates to this standard SQL expression (which can be used starting with SQL Server 2022):

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM b THEN c
  WHEN a IS NOT DISTINCT FROM d THEN e
  ELSE f
END
```

In older SQL Server versions, an emulation using `EXISTS` and `INTERSECT` is possible:

```sql
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT a INTERSECT SELECT b) THEN c
  WHEN EXISTS (SELECT a INTERSECT SELECT d) THEN e
  ELSE f
END
```

Comment: It appears that as of 2023, SQL Server 2022 (16.x) supports `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/is-distinct-from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16