# Oracle Decode function equivalent in Sql Server 2005+

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DECODE( ) function in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559241/decode-function-in-sql-server)

Is there a direct equivalent of [Oracles Decode](http://psoug.org/definition/DECOMPOSE.htm) function in SQL Server (2005 or later)?

If not, is there another way of accomplishing the same effects as DECODE?

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent sql command is a CASE statement:

For example:

```
declare @t table(id int identity,code varchar(25))
insert @t(code)
  select 'A' UNION ALL
  select 'B' UNION ALL
  select 'C' UNION ALL
  select 'D' UNION ALL
  select 'E' UNION ALL
  select 'F'  
  select * from @t
  --
  select id,code,
         case id 
              when 1  then code++convert(varchar(10),id)
              when 2  then code++convert(varchar(10),id)
              else 'UNDEFINED-DECODE VALUE for id : '+convert(varchar(10),id)
         end  as DECODEDVALUE
  from @t
  --
```

Returns this dataset:

```
id          code                      DECODEDVALUE
----------- ------------------------- ------------------------------------------
1           A                         A1
2           B                         B2
3           C                         UNDEFINED-DECODE VALUE for id : 3
4           D                         UNDEFINED-DECODE VALUE for id : 4
5           E                         UNDEFINED-DECODE VALUE for id : 5
6           F                         UNDEFINED-DECODE VALUE for id : 6
```