# How can I convert Oracle round statement to SQL server syntax?

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008

How can I convert:

`round(DECODE(PC_TTL.WAGETYPE, 3085, PC_TTL.WORKHOURS, DECODE(PC_TTL.UNIT, '010', PC_TTL.WORKHOURS/8, PC_TTL.WORKHOURS)) , 2)`

to SQL server syntax?

Comment: I may be wrong, but since SQL Server also has a `ROUND` function I suspect that the real problem you have is with converting `DECODE`, not `ROUND`, and that question has [already been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559241/decode-function-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood the `DECODE` logic, this should do the trick:

```
ROUND(
  CASE WHEN PC_TTL.WAGETYPE = 3085 THEN PC_TTL.WORKHOURS
  ELSE
    CASE WHEN PC_TTL.UNIT = '010' THEN PC_TTL.WORKHOURS/8
    ELSE PC_TTL.WORKHOURS
    END
  END, 2)
```

This will work in SQL Server *and* Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple case statement.

```
    ROUND (
CASE
    WHEN PC_TTL.WAGETYPE = 3085  THEN PC_TTL.WORKHOURS
    WHEN PC_TTL.UNIT     = '010' THEN PC_TTL.WORKHOURS / 8
    ELSE PC_TTL.WORKHOURS
END, 2 )
```