# Get AVG ignoring Null or Zero values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I get the `AVG` of a column ignoring `NULL` and zero values?

I have three columns to get their average, I try to use the following script:

```
SELECT distinct
     AVG(cast(ISNULL(a.SecurityW,0) as bigint)) as Average1
     ,AVG(cast(ISNULL(a.TransferW,0) as bigint)) as Average2
     ,AVG(cast(ISNULL(a.StaffW,0) as bigint)) as Average3
FROM Table1 a,  Table2 b
WHERE a.SecurityW <> 0 AND a.SecurityW IS NOT NULL
AND a.TransferW<> 0 AND a.TransferWIS NOT NULL
AND a.StaffW<> 0 AND a.StaffWIS NOT NULL
AND MONTH(a.ActualTime) = 4
AND YEAR(a.ActualTime) = 2013
```

I don't get any results, however the three columns have values including NULL and zeros!

Is there anyway to exclude null values before getting the average?

example: `AVERAGE(NOTNULL(SecurityW))`

Comment: All those `AND`s mean that you'll only get rows which have non-NULL values in all 3 columns. Also, your `NOT NULL` checks aren't required, since `Column<>0` evaluates as `UNKNOWN` if `Column` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 80):

`NULL` is already ignored so you can use `NULLIF` to turn `0` to `NULL`. Also you don't need `DISTINCT` and your `WHERE` on `ActualTime` is not sargable.

```
SELECT AVG(cast(NULLIF(a.SecurityW, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Average1,
       AVG(cast(NULLIF(a.TransferW, 0) AS BIGINT)) AS Average2,
       AVG(cast(NULLIF(a.StaffW, 0) AS BIGINT))    AS Average3
FROM   Table1 a
WHERE  a.ActualTime >= '20130401'
       AND a.ActualTime < '20130501'
```

PS I have no idea what `Table2 b` is in the original query for as there is no join condition for it so have omitted it from my answer.

Comment: btw I don't think you achve anything by converting an integer to bigint

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - It can prevent an arithmetic overflow error if the `SUM` is too large. `SELECT AVG(C) FROM (SELECT 2147483647 UNION ALL SELECT 2147483647) T(C)` fails but `SELECT AVG(CAST(C AS BIGINT)) FROM (SELECT 2147483647 UNION ALL SELECT 2147483647) T(C)` succeeds.

Comment: @DanielGimenez your solution currently doesn't ignore 0 correctly. This answer does using nullif.

Comment: @DanielGimenez - No it won't. Try it. `SELECT AVG(NULLIF(C,0)) FROM (SELECT 30 UNION ALL SELECT null UNION ALL SELECT 0) T(C)` returns `30`

Answer (score 16):

this should work, haven't tried though. this will exclude zero. NULL is excluded by default

```
AVG (CASE WHEN SecurityW <> 0 THEN SecurityW ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 13):

In Case of not considering '0' or 'NULL' in average function.
Simply use

```
AVG(NULLIF(your_column_name,0))
```

Answer (score 4):

worked for me：

```
AVG(CASE WHEN SecurityW <> 0 THEN SecurityW ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 1):

You already attempt to filter out `NULL` values with `NOT NULL`.  I have changed this to `IS NOT NULL` in the `WHERE` clause so it will execute.  We can refactor this by removing the `ISNULL` function in the `AVG` method.  Also, I doubt you'll actually need `bigint` so we can remove the cast.

```
SELECT distinct
     AVG(a.SecurityW) as Average1
     ,AVG(a.TransferW) as Average2
     ,AVG(a.StaffW) as Average3
FROM Table1 a,  Table2 b
WHERE a.SecurityW <> 0 AND a.SecurityW IS NOT NULL
AND a.TransferW<> 0 AND a.TransferWIS IS NOT NULL
AND a.StaffW<> 0 AND a.StaffWIS IS NOT NULL
AND MONTH(a.ActualTime) = 4
AND YEAR(a.ActualTime) = 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Null values are anyways excluded from the avg calculation. If you need to exclude zero values as well, you could simply use the decode function inside your avg function:-

```
SELECT AVG(decode(a.SecurityW,0,null,a.SecurityW)) as Average1
 ,AVG(decode(a.TransferW,0,null,a.TransferW)) as Average2
 ,AVG(decode(a.StaffW,0,null,a.StaffW)) as Average3 
FROM Table1 a,  Table2 b
WHERE MONTH(a.ActualTime) = 4
AND YEAR(a.ActualTime) = 2013;
```

Comment: Note: DECODE is Oracle. See this for Sql Server equivalence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559241/decode-function-in-sql-server