# MYSQL: Get average of fields in case where value is not a certain value

Tags: mysql, sql, average

Say I have a table with 5 columns,

A, B, C, D, E

that are integers. I want to get the average of all of the fields in that case, that are not 3.

So, on some sample data:

```
A, B, C, D, E         DESIRED RESULT
-------------
1, 1, 4, 4, 3       -> 2.5 (NOT 2.6)
1, 2, 3, 3, 3       -> 1.5 (NOT 2.4)
```

EDIT: I found a solution.

```
(
   (
    IF(A!=3,A,0)
   +IF(B!=3,B,0)
   +IF(C!=3,C,0)
   +IF(D!=3,D,0) 
   +IF(E!=3,E,0)
   ) 
   /
   (
    IF(A!=3,1,0)
   +IF(B!=3,1,0)
   +IF(C!=3,1,0)
   +IF(D!=3,1,0)
   +IF(E!=3,1,0)
   )
) as VALUE
```

Comment: Do you have any queries that you tried?

Comment: `AVG(...)` will ignore nulls, so you don't need to make this so complicated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get AVG ignoring Null or Zero values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425011/get-avg-ignoring-null-or-zero-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
  select avg(CASE WHEN A = 3 then 0 else A end +
             CASE WHEN B = 3 then 0 else B end +
             CASE WHEN C = 3 then 0 else C end +
             CASE WHEN D = 3 then 0 else D end +
             CASE WHEN E = 3 then 0 else E end)/
         (CASE WHEN A = 3  then 0 else 1 end +
          CASE WHEN B = 3  then 0 else 1 end +
          CASE WHEN C = 3  then 0 else 1 end +
          CASE WHEN D = 3  then 0 else 1 end +
          CASE WHEN E = 3  then 0 else 1 end) as av from table1
  group by A,B,C,D,E
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c57799/9)

Comment: same idea if you do it with IF statment.