# TSQL Group, Count and Sum dataset not giving expected result

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, aggregate

Say I have a query that returns none grouped data, as the first query below does, and I wish to group the data by summing and counting some fields and grouping on the remaining fields, as shown in the second query.

Why in this case do the count fields return 2 instead of the expected 1?

**EDIT:**
I have just realized its counting distinct rows so in the RequestsOnSite it has 114065 and 0 resulting in a count of 2. Is there a way to discount 0 valued cells?

*Query:*

```
SELECT 'Month' AS [Period],
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionCode,'') AS RegionCode,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionName,'') AS RegionName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    SR01.ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(LCRep.RepName,'') AS RepName,
    CASE WHEN ProductivityRequests.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityRequests.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR ProductivityRequests.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON') THEN ProductivityRequests.ReportKey ELSE 0 END AS RequestsOnSite,
    CASE WHEN ProductivityHours.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityHours.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR ProductivityHours.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalOnSiteTime ELSE 0 END AS HoursOnSite,
    CASE WHEN ProductivityRequests.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityRequests.OnOffSite = 'OF' OR ProductivityRequests.OnOffSiteSvc = 'OF') THEN ProductivityRequests.ReportKey ELSE 0 END AS RequestsOffSite,
    CASE WHEN ProductivityHours.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityHours.OnOffSite = 'OF' OR ProductivityHours.OnOffSiteSvc = 'OF') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalOffSiteTime ELSE 0 END AS HoursOffSite,
    CASE WHEN (ProductivityRequests.RequestType = 'NR') THEN ProductivityRequests.ReportKey ELSE 0 END AS RequestsNonReport,
    CASE WHEN (ProductivityHours.RequestType = 'NR') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalNonReportTime ELSE 0 END AS HoursNonReport,
    ProductivityRequests.OnOffSite,
    ProductivityRequests.OnOffSiteSvc
FROM SR01
    INNER JOIN ProductivityHours ON ProductivityHours.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    INNER JOIN ProductivityRequests ON ProductivityRequests.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN LCRep ON SR01.ServicingRep = LCRep.RepID
    LEFT JOIN Branch ON SR01.ServicingBranch = Branch.BranchID
    LEFT JOIN Region ON Region.RegionCode = Branch.Region
    LEFT JOIN Zone ON Zone.ZoneAbbrev = Region.Zone 
WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
    AND SR01.[Status]='X'
    AND SR01.DateComplete BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateTo), 0) AND @DateTo
    AND Zone.ZoneID IN (@Zone)
    AND Region.RegionCode IN (@Region)
    AND Branch.BranchID IN (@Branch)
    AND LCRep.RepID IN(@RepID)  
    AND (@EquipmentBreakdown = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.EB = @EquipmentBreakdown)) 
    AND (@PropertyCasualty = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.PC = @PropertyCasualty))
```

NOTE: OnOffSite and OnOffSiteSvc are shown here just for clarity and will not appear in the final query.

*Resultset*

[image]

*Aggregate query*

```
SELECT 'Month' AS [Period],
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionCode,'') AS RegionCode,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionName,'') AS RegionName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    SR01.ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(LCRep.RepName,'') AS RepName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityRequests.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityRequests.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR ProductivityRequests.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON') THEN ProductivityRequests.ReportKey ELSE 0 END) AS RequestsOnSite,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityHours.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityHours.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR ProductivityHours.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalOnSiteTime ELSE 0 END) AS HoursOnSite,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityRequests.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityRequests.OnOffSite = 'OF' OR ProductivityRequests.OnOffSiteSvc = 'OF') THEN ProductivityRequests.ReportKey ELSE 0 END) AS RequestsOffSite,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityHours.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityHours.OnOffSite = 'OF' OR ProductivityHours.OnOffSiteSvc = 'OF') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalOffSiteTime ELSE 0 END) AS HoursOffSite,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (ProductivityRequests.RequestType = 'NR') THEN ProductivityRequests.ReportKey ELSE 0 END) AS RequestsNonReport,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (ProductivityHours.RequestType = 'NR') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalNonReportTime ELSE 0 END) AS HoursNonReport
FROM SR01
    INNER JOIN ProductivityHours ON ProductivityHours.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    INNER JOIN ProductivityRequests ON ProductivityRequests.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN LCRep ON SR01.ServicingRep = LCRep.RepID
    LEFT JOIN Branch ON SR01.ServicingBranch = Branch.BranchID
    LEFT JOIN Region ON Region.RegionCode = Branch.Region
    LEFT JOIN Zone ON Zone.ZoneAbbrev = Region.Zone 
WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
    AND SR01.[Status]='X'
    AND SR01.DateComplete BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateTo), 0) AND @DateTo
    AND Zone.ZoneID IN (@Zone)
    AND Region.RegionCode IN (@Region)
    AND Branch.BranchID IN (@Branch)
    AND LCRep.RepID IN(@RepID)  
    AND (@EquipmentBreakdown = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.EB = @EquipmentBreakdown)) 
    AND (@PropertyCasualty = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.PC = @PropertyCasualty))
GROUP BY Zone.ZoneID, Zone.ZoneName, Region.RegionCode, Region.RegionName, Branch.BranchID, BranchName, SR01.ServicingRep, LCRep.RepName
```

*Resultset:*

[image]

Note that the RequestsOnSite, RequestsOffSite and RequestsNonReport all contain 2 rather than the expected 1.

Comment: can't you just put a condition on the where clause?

Comment: @Jayvee, I don't see how that would work as the filtering and aggregation is done within the individual 'CASE WHEN' clauses and the underlying view does not contain counts, just the underlying data I want to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the answer was to use the [NullIF operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms177562.aspx) as discussed in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425011/get-avg-ignoring-null-or-zero-values)

The resultant query would look like this

```
SELECT 'Month' AS [Period],
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneID,'') AS ZoneID,
    ISNULL(Zone.ZoneName,'') AS ZoneName,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionCode,'') AS RegionCode,
    ISNULL(Region.RegionName,'') AS RegionName,
    Branch.BranchID,
    ISNULL(Branch.BranchName,'') AS BranchName,
    SR01.ServicingRep,
    ISNULL(LCRep.RepName,'') AS RepName,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityRequests.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityRequests.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR ProductivityRequests.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON') THEN NULLIF(ProductivityRequests.ReportKey, 0) ELSE NULL END) AS RequestsOnSite,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityHours.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityHours.OnOffSite = 'ON' OR ProductivityHours.OnOffSiteSvc = 'ON') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalOnSiteTime ELSE 0 END) AS HoursOnSite,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityRequests.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityRequests.OnOffSite = 'OF' OR ProductivityRequests.OnOffSiteSvc = 'OF') THEN NULLIF(ProductivityRequests.ReportKey, 0) ELSE NULL END) AS RequestsOffSite,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ProductivityHours.RequestType <> 'MN' AND (ProductivityHours.OnOffSite = 'OF' OR ProductivityHours.OnOffSiteSvc = 'OF') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalOffSiteTime ELSE 0 END) AS HoursOffSite,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (ProductivityRequests.RequestType = 'NR') THEN NULLIF(ProductivityRequests.ReportKey, 0) ELSE NULL END) AS RequestsNonReport,
    SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN (ProductivityHours.RequestType = 'NR') THEN ProductivityHours.TotalNonReportTime ELSE 0 END) AS HoursNonReport
FROM SR01
    INNER JOIN ProductivityHours ON ProductivityHours.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    INNER JOIN ProductivityRequests ON ProductivityRequests.ReportKey = SR01.ReportKey
    LEFT JOIN LCRep ON SR01.ServicingRep = LCRep.RepID
    LEFT JOIN Branch ON SR01.ServicingBranch = Branch.BranchID
    LEFT JOIN Region ON Region.RegionCode = Branch.Region
    LEFT JOIN Zone ON Zone.ZoneAbbrev = Region.Zone 
WHERE ISNULL(SR01.ServicingBranch,'-') <> '-'
    AND SR01.[Status]='X'
    AND SR01.DateComplete BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @DateTo), 0) AND @DateTo
    AND Zone.ZoneID IN (@Zone)
    AND Region.RegionCode IN (@Region)
    AND Branch.BranchID IN (@Branch)
    AND LCRep.RepID IN(@RepID)  
    AND (@EquipmentBreakdown = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.EB = @EquipmentBreakdown)) 
    AND (@PropertyCasualty = 0 OR (@EquipmentBreakdown = 1 AND @PropertyCasualty = 1) OR (LCRep.PC = @PropertyCasualty))
GROUP BY Zone.ZoneID, Zone.ZoneName, Region.RegionCode, Region.RegionName, Branch.BranchID, BranchName, SR01.ServicingRep, LCRep.RepName
```