# Make AVG() ignore 0's?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, average

I have a column where I can get 0 values, but I need to calculate the average of that column without counting those 0's as part of the divider.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(CAST(RATING AS NUMERIC(18, 2))) AS AVERAGE,
       QUESTIONID,
       Questions.SHORTVERSION,
       COUNT(CASE
                 WHEN RATING > 0
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE NULL
             END) AS COUNT
FROM AnswersRating
     INNER JOIN Questions ON Questions.ID = QUESTIONID
WHERE SURVEYID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM SURVEYS
    WHERE FLIGHTDATAID = '8371'
)
GROUP BY QUESTIONID,
         Questions.SHORTVERSION
ORDER BY QUESTIONID;
```

I read somewhere that I can use `NULLIF` to help this, but I couldn't figure out how to use it correctly. Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: You can use NULLIF.           NULLIF(RATING, 0)

Comment: can you not add `where rating > 0`?

Comment: I'm agree with @vkp ,  where your_col != 0

Comment: this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425011/get-avg-ignoring-null-or-zero-values/46947376#46947376

Answer (score 7):

You can use NULLIF to convert your 0s into NULLs as AVG will ignore NULLs:

```
NULLIF(RATING, 0)
```