# Postgres Average calculation ignores null

Tags: postgresql

This is my postgres table

```
 name   | revenue   
--------+---------  
 John   |     100  
 Will   |     100  
 Tom    |     100   
 Susan  |     100   
 Ben    |        
(5 rows)
```

Here, when I calculate average for revenue, It returns 100, which is clearly not the case and sum/count, which is 400/5 is 80.  Is this behaviour by conventional design or am I missing the point?

I know I could [change null to 0 and process as usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425011/get-avg-ignoring-null-or-zero-values) .  But, given the default behaviour, is this intentional and preferred way of calculating average.

Comment: This is how the behaviour of aggregates is defined in the SQL standard. So yes, this is intentional

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is both intentional and perfectly logical. Remember that `NULL` means that the value is *unknown*.

It might, for instance, represent a value which will be filled in at some future date. If the future value turns out to be `0`, the average will be `400 / 5 = 80`, as you say; but if the future value turns out to be `200`, the average value will be `600 / 5 = 120` instead. All we can know right now is that the average of *known* values is `400 / 4 = 100`.

If you actually know that you have `0` revenue for this item, you should store `0` in that column. If you don't know what revenue you have for that item, you should exclude it from your calculations, which is what Postgres, following the SQL Standard, does for you.

If you can't fix the data, but it is in fact a case that all `NULL`s in this table should be treated as `0` - or as some other fixed value - you can use a `COALESCE` inside the aggregate:

```
 SELECT AVG(COALESCE(revenue, 0)) as forced_average
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should force a 0 value for null revenues.

> ```
> create table tbl (name varchar(10), revenue int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into tbl values
> ('John', 100), ('Will', 100), ('Tom', 100), ('Susan', 100), ('Ben', null);
> ```
>
> ```
> 5 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select avg(case when revenue is null then 0 else revenue end) from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> |                 avg |
> | ------------------: |
> | 80.0000000000000000 |
> ```

> ```
> select avg(coalesce(revenue,0)) from tbl;
> ```
>
> ```
> |                 avg |
> | ------------------: |
> | 80.0000000000000000 |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6e204e7e1ecaed4f2c9a54224ff02571)*