# Include or Exclude else in a CASE expression

Tags: sql, postgresql

PostgreSQL question:

Run the following two queries in the employees database.

```
SELECT
       AVG(
            CASE
                  WHEN emp_no = 90689 THEN salary
                  ELSE 0
             END
       ) AS emp_90689_salary
FROM salaries;

SELECT
       AVG(
            CASE
                  WHEN emp_no = 90689 THEN salary
             END
       ) AS emp_90689_salary
FROM salaries;
```

Question 1: What is the difference between these two queries?

Question 2: Why are they giving different outputs?

---

I was thinking that with no ELSE, a query would only consider the average of employee # 90689 or something. I still am confused about what the answer is to the above questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres Average calculation ignores null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557047/postgres-average-calculation-ignores-null)

Comment: Please specify what Employee table, give reference or create statement or your question becomes too general

Answer (score 2):

The difference between those two queries is the treatment of nulls. According to the SQL Standard nulls represent *missing* data.

- The first query *includes* the missing data by considering their value as zero.
- The second query *excludes* the missing data.

For example, if the table as: (`100`, `140`, `null`) the first query will do `(100 + 140 + 0) / 3 = 80`, while the second one will exclude the last entry and will do `(100 + 140) / 2 = 120`.

In the end, it's up to you how to deal with missing data. Depending on your business definition you may want to use the first strategy or the second one. Both are correct, depending on the business logic.

Comment: Could you be more specific in terms of what salaries are being included in the average salary of the first query and what salaries are being included in the average salary of the 2nd query?

Comment: In the 1st query, it is taking ( employee #90689 salary) + 0 + 0 ... + 0 / n, right? n is the total number of employees and 0 are the salaries of every employee that is NOT employee # 90689.

Comment: @AmirMonir That is correct.

Comment: So is the 1st query taking the average of the salaries of all employees NOT employee # 90689 (NULL values) AND salary employee # 90689 together?

Comment: While the 2nd query will only take the average of salary employee # 90689 and exclude all other employees?

Comment: Is that the difference between these two queries?

Comment: @AmirMonir Yes, the second query will only take the average salary of employee #90689.