# How to handle zero divisor in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

I want to get the average value in column containing ColumnA/ColumnB using SQL.

[image]

However it is required for the SQL to ignore the zeros. This means the requirement is to process the average as if the zeros were NULLS. As below:

[image]

Notice that the average value is higher when zero is replaced by NULL as in the above excel data i.e 0.999342 instead of 0.70786694.

Here is the SQL query to generate average:

```
SELECT StartTime, AVG(ColumnA/ColumnB)
FROM Table
where StartTime between '02-SEP-19 12:00:00.000000000 AM' 
and '02-SEP-19 11:59:59.000000000 PM' 
group StartTime 
ORDER BY StartTime
```

My question is what value can I use to replace the zeros inside the SQL database so that the the SQL query would derive average values as if NULLs were used.

Comment: head over to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425011/get-avg-ignoring-null-or-zero-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get AVG ignoring Null or Zero values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425011/get-avg-ignoring-null-or-zero-values)

Comment: Usually I use `AVG(DECODE(ColumnB,0,NULL, ColumnA/ColumnB))`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`NULLIF`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm):

```
SELECT StartTime, AVG(ColumnA/NULLIF(ColumnB,0))
FROM Table
where StartTime between '02-SEP-19 12:00:00.000000000 AM' 
  and '02-SEP-19 11:59:59.000000000 PM' 
group StartTime 
ORDER BY StartTime
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. The NULLIF function works, but I am still required to insert the generated results of the query into a different table. The problem now is that the unwanted zero values replace the null values once the insertion is done.

Comment: @ResearchIT Could you provide `CREATE TABLE` statement for table that you are trying to insernt into?