# how to get zero instead of null

Tags: sql-server-2008

My question is i have to show this ClosingAdv and ClosingDebt coloumns as zero when its null.

```
SELECT 
  a.StudentCode, c.FullName, a.CentreCode, a.FeesCode,
  a.InstOrYear, c.FullName, d.BranchName, b.TotalPayment, 
  a.BalanceAmt,
  CASE 
     WHEN (b.TotalPayment > a.BalanceAmt) THEN (b.TotalPayment - a.BalanceAmt) 
     WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
  END as ClosingAdv,
  CASE 
 WHEN (a.BalanceAmt > b.TotalPayment) THEN (a.BalanceAmt - b.TotalPayment)
 WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
  END as ClosingDebt
```

Comment: Use it for reference 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559241/decode-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: You should be able to use the ISNULL() function which is available in Microsoft SQL Server.  Which is the primary data column that you wish to check for NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another case to the statement as well as using `ISNULL()` as suggested above.

```
SELECT 
  a.StudentCode, c.FullName, a.CentreCode, a.FeesCode,
  a.InstOrYear, c.FullName, d.BranchName, b.TotalPayment, 
  a.BalanceAmt,
  CASE 
     WHEN (b.TotalPayment > a.BalanceAmt) THEN (b.TotalPayment - a.BalanceAmt) 
     WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
     WHEN b.TotalPayment is NULL then '0'
  END as ClosingAdv,
  CASE 
 WHEN (a.BalanceAmt > b.TotalPayment) THEN (a.BalanceAmt - b.TotalPayment)
 WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
 WHEN a.BalanceAmt is NULL then '0'
  END as ClosingDebt
```

Comment: thanks ..my intention is  when ClosingDebt got some value then ClosingAdv=0 and when ClosingAdv got some value ClosingDebt =0

Comment: Please tell me exactly what's the problem of your original code. Which column give you null value?

Comment: i should show like is 1st case in above program happens 2nd case value should be zero i mean                                      CASE 
     WHEN (b.TotalPayment > a.BalanceAmt) THEN (b.TotalPayment - a.BalanceAmt) 
     WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'                           END as ClosingAdv                                                    if this case true then at a time in 2nd case ClosingDebt should appear as zero simultaneously

Comment: sure...sir...i got required output jus i kept one statement..CASE 
         WHEN (b.TotalPayment > a.BalanceAmt) THEN (b.TotalPayment - a.BalanceAmt) 
         WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
         else '0'
         
END as ClosingAdv,
CASE 
      WHEN (a.BalanceAmt > b.TotalPayment) THEN (a.BalanceAmt - b.TotalPayment)
      WHEN (b.TotalPayment = a.BalanceAmt) then '0'
      else '0'
END as ClosingDebt